# Why an empty list does not equal False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The pythonic way to test if a list is empty is:

```
empty_list = []
if not empty_list:
    print("The list is empty")
```

output: The list is empty

Then this code should have the same output:

```
empty_list = []
if empty_list == False:
    print("The list is empty")
```

but the output is different (does not print anything), hence an empty list does not equal to neither `True` or `False`. This can also be checked with:

```
>>> [] == True , [] == False
(False, False)
```

Furthermore, we can also do:

```
bool([])
```

output: False

I am totally puzzled, why the first example works but not the others?

Comment: An empty list is still a `list` - so it cannot possibly be `False` - which is a boolean object. That's why the `bool` function exists - to get the boolean equivalent of an object.

Comment: It is "falsy" but not `False`.

Comment: Using `not x` call the `__bool__` method of `x`. It could be interesting to take a close look to this function.

Comment: @Paul I tried that already, but you get: ``'list' object has no attribute '__bool__'``. I believe is the same as using bool()